# Runtime - sigsegv error in the below code

Tags: c++

Problem statement link :-http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/range-query/

My solution :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     long long n=0,q=0,x=0,y=0,val=0; //initialize variables
     int a[1000];
    int counter=0;
    cin >>n ;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >>a[i];  //populate the array
    }
    cin >>q;

    for (int k=0;k<q;k++)
    {
        cin >>x >>y >>val;
            for (int j=x;j<=y;j++)
            {
                    if (a[j]==val)
                        counter++;

            }
    cout <<counter << "\n";
    x=0;
    y=0;
    val=0;
    counter=0;
    a[10]=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:- 
 sigsegv error encountered while executing the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N is 10^4 in the question ,your  maximum array size is 1000.

```
int a[1000];//Make this 10000
```